# Symfony 3.3.8 игнорирование кастомного нормалайзера

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

Создаю в качестве примера нормалайзер для исключений

src/AppBundle/Serializer/Normalizer/ExceptionNormalizer.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Serializer\Normalizer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

/**
 * Class ExceptionNormalizer
 */
class ExceptionNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array()): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof \Exception;
    }
}
```

Прописываю его в сервисах

src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
    ...
    app.normalizer.exception:
        class: AppBundle\Serializer\Normalizer\ExceptionNormalizer
        tags:
            - { name: serializer.normalizer }
```

app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    #- { resource: services.yml } exclude default services file
    - { resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

При срабатывании исключения возвращается это

> {"error":{"code":404,"message":"Not Found","exception":[{"message":"AppBundle\Entity\User object not found.","class":"Symfony\Component.....

Хотя ожидается это

> {}

Что бы не менял в нормалайзере, ответ при исключении не меняется. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а вы уверены, что используется именно нормалайзер (который регистрируется в сериалайзере) для нормализации исключения?